# Only the first match is being considered (Python Re)

Tags: python, regex

**Different substrings in a string that start and end with given strings**

Given a string s and two other strings begin and end, find the number of different substrings in the string which begin and end with the given begin and end strings.

Examples:

```
Input : s = "geeksforgeeks"
        begin = "geeks"
        end = "for"
Output : 1

Input : s = "vishakha"
        begin = "h"
        end = "a"
Output : 2
Two different sub-strings are "ha" and "hakha".
```

**My Approach so far**

```
import re

def find_from_right(string,reg):
    s = ""
    match = []
    for c in string:
        s = s+c
        for i in re.findall(reg, s):
            match.append(i)
    return match

print(find_from_right(str(raw_input()),r".*c.*d$"))
```

**Output:** `['cod', 'codecppforfood']`

The problem is that it is not matching strings like:

```
cppforfood
```

**It is considering only the first match.**

Can someone please point out the mistake ?

Comment: I suggest you change the question title, I believe that's why you are getting downvoted.

Comment: thanks. will do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all occurrences of start and end symbol in your string using regular expression and construct answer with list comprehension:

```
s = input("Enter String: ")
head = input("Enter start: ")
tail = input("Enter end: ")

result = list(set([s[i.start():j.start() + 1] 
                   for i in re.finditer(head, s) for j in re.finditer(tail, s)
                   if i.start() < j.start()]))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['cod', 'codecppforfood', 'cppforfood']
```

Comment: This does not work, for `vishakha` as input and, with `h` as start and `a` at end only prints `['hakha']`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `re.compile` and `re.findall` with the `regex` module to find overlapping matches.

```
import regex 

s = "geeksforgeeks"
begin = "geeks"
end = "for"

first_pattern = regex.compile(''.join(begin+'[a-zA-Z]*'+end))
print(regex.findall(first_pattern,s,overlapped=True));

s = "vishakha"
begin = "h"
end = "a"

second_pattern = regex.compile(''.join(begin+'[a-zA-Z]*'+end))
print(regex.findall(second_pattern,s,overlapped=True));
```

Code above prints:

```
['geeksfor']
['hakha', 'ha']
```

Comment: It says: TypeError: findall() got an unexpected keyword argument 'overlapped'

Comment: Like I said this works with the regex module, do you have the `regex` module installed?